# how to store repeater control value to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to store the repeater control value to database table. I have a repeater control with three lable with corresponding textbox.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeatInformation" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="style3"> 
         <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.fldleavename")%>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" ></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

repeater control format:

```
  Casual Leave  : Textbox1
  Medical Leave : Textbox1
  Annual Leave  : Textbox1
```

how can i store the repeater value to database. I don't have an idea for storing this value please help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeatInformation.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox1");

        //Now you have your textbox to do with what you like
        //You can access the .Text property to find the new value that needs saving to the database
    }
}
```

On a side note. I would consider revising the names of your controls. It'll make life a lot easier in the future if you adopt some sort of convention and use camel case.

With regards to saving this to a database - it entirely depends on how you're dealing with data access at the moment. That's another question altogether I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in list object & then bind it into data table in database.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your datatable and updated into database using SQLDataAdapter

Answer (score -1):

`enter code here`
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
            {
            //Create object for database
            // Get Data from rep controls
            // using e.Item
            // store it into database
         }
    }

Comment: Why would he want to store the value of the textBox on databound to the database? If I understand the way the op is binding this data to the database it's going to be 'fresh out of the database'. What you're proposing is that he binds the data and immediately on binding re-save to the database.

Comment: use above code when you want to store data while databound to repeater. otherwise used Daniel McNulty strategy

Comment: Fernando, used the daniel post

Comment: Your code wasn't wrong as such Hiren, it's just that in this particular instance it's not really practical. If Fernando was binding a different data source to the repeater than where he were to save the data in the repeater your method could be used.

Comment: Ya, I got it. Thank you Daniel